# Put marker on the image in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'm showing an image using `cv::imshow("binary1", binary1);`. I want to put a marker on the image to the check the pixel locations. How can I put marker on the image for a particular row and column value?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to understand what is it that you want to do, but I wrote a code a while back that [displays the RGB color of a pixel along with it's coordinates on the title of the window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14918425/176769). Move the mouse pointer over the image and you'll see it change.

It uses a Qt window, though. You can check [cvImage](https://github.com/karlphillip/GraphicsProgramming/tree/master/cvImage).